# Non-generators of $A_n$

Tags: group-theory

It is known that all alternating groups $A_n$ can be generated by 2 elements, this goes back to 1901 (Miller). Moreover, the long lasting conjecture by Netto that the probability that 2 elements of $A_n$ chosen uniformly at random generate the whole of $A_n$ tends to $1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ was proved some 40 years ago by Dixon. So almost all pairs of elements from $A_n$ generate $A_n$.

In the case $n=5$, what's the easiest way of finding all the pairs of elements which do NOT generate the whole group?

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty easy method: I just asked GAP. :-)

It computes conjugacy classes of non-generators. It displays their size, the group they generate (instead of A5), and representatives of the generators. About 36% of pairs are non-generators.

``

```
gap> non:=Filtered(Combinations(AsSet(AlternatingGroup(5)),2),x->Size(Group(x))<60);;
gap> orbs:=Orbits(AlternatingGroup(5),non,OnSets);;
gap> PrintArray(List(orbs,o->[Size(o),o[1]]));
[ [ 20,      C3,               [ (), (3,4,5) ] ],
  [ 15,      C2,            [ (), (2,3)(4,5) ] ],
  [ 12,      C5,           [ (), (1,2,3,4,5) ] ],
  [ 12,      C5,           [ (), (1,2,3,5,4) ] ],
  [ 10,      C3,          [ (3,4,5), (3,5,4) ] ],
  [ 60,      A4,       [ (3,4,5), (2,3)(4,5) ] ],
  [ 60,      A4,          [ (3,4,5), (2,3,4) ] ],
  [ 30,      A4,          [ (3,4,5), (2,3,5) ] ],
  [ 60,      S3,       [ (3,4,5), (1,2)(4,5) ] ],
  [ 60,      A4,       [ (3,4,5), (1,3)(4,5) ] ],
  [ 30,      A4,          [ (3,4,5), (1,3,5) ] ],
  [ 15, C2 x C2,    [ (2,3)(4,5), (2,4)(3,5) ] ],
  [ 30,      S3,    [ (2,3)(4,5), (1,2)(4,5) ] ],
  [ 30,     D10,    [ (2,3)(4,5), (1,2)(3,4) ] ],
  [ 30,     D10,    [ (2,3)(4,5), (1,2)(3,5) ] ],
  [ 60,     D10,   [ (2,3)(4,5), (1,2,4,5,3) ] ],
  [ 60,     D10,   [ (2,3)(4,5), (1,2,5,4,3) ] ],
  [ 12,      C5,  [ (1,2,3,4,5), (1,3,5,2,4) ] ],
  [ 12,      C5,  [ (1,2,3,4,5), (1,4,2,5,3) ] ],
  [  6,      C5,  [ (1,2,3,4,5), (1,5,4,3,2) ] ],
  [  6,      C5,  [ (1,2,3,5,4), (1,4,5,3,2) ] ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Maple, there are $630$ such pairs in $A_{5}$.

```
> with( GroupTheory ):
> L := select( gens -> GroupOrder( Group( gens ) ) < 60, combinat:-choose( Elements( Alt( 5 ) ), 2 )  ):
> nops( L );
                  630

> L[ 1 ];
            {1,  (3, 4, 5)}

> L[ 2 ];
        { (3, 4, 5),  (1, 3, 4)}
```

You could do an equivalent computation in other computer algebra systems like GAP or Magma.